# Should I use ARC when coding in Objective-C++?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c

I work on a Objective-C++ library project. So far there is only one ObjC object wrapped inside a C++ singleton object in my C++-based codebase. But the client code of the library is likely to use ARC throughout.

There are cases where I need to translate ObjC structures, i.e., structures containing ObjC object members, into their C(++) counterparts.

I read from this post:

http://philjordan.eu/article/mixing-objective-c-c++-and-objective-c++

that:

> Even if you use ARC in your project, I recommend you disable it for
>   C++-heavy Objective-C++ files like this one. You can make your C++
>   code behave itself even with ARC, but it'll often be more work than
>   just putting in the release and retain calls.

The author didn't go in detail of how he reached this conclusion. The post was last updated in 2012. I wonder if there is any significant concern behind this or it is simply  outdated info as ObjC evolves.

Thanks!

Comment: From my experience I would disagree with disabling ARC. You will certainly want to keep your c++ header files "clean" (i.e. no objective-c objects or syntax in them, all external-facing c++ objects should have a c++ declaration and a objective-c++ pimpl implementation).

Comment: From a consistency standpoint, I like the idea of disabling ARC when mixing in C++ code. You're already forced to explicitly manage the memory of your C++ pointers, so adding the requirement for your Obj-C pointers makes my brain happier.

Comment: Nobody should ever be explicitly managing the lifetime of c++ pointers. We have unique_ptr and shared_ptr for that purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've been using c++/objc mixes and arc/no-arc with no problems.
The only thing that happens in arc is that objc automagically adds retain/release in most places that uses objc objects.
If your c++ class is going to use objc objects, then it also will need to be objc enabled - in that case, arc will just work if it's enabled (and allowed for the file). Otherwise you'll need to retain/release manually. ARC doesn't affect c++ memory management, so there's nothing more to it.

So unless you want to use void* for objc objects and have no objc support in your c++ code, then just follow arc/non-arc rules and it should be fine.

My guess why you might want to have no arc in c++ file is to avoid excessive retain/release calls that arc tends to add sometimes - so basically, if you know where you really need to retain objects (which compiler doesn't know and retains everywhere), so you can get app doing a bit less computations. Also weak references might break things when used in wrong places (like in c++ hashed set or as keys in map, places that might get reallocated), in simple situations they usually work.